# IntelliJ: Unresolved function for dependencies module

Tags: intellij-idea, erlang, rebar3

I use rebar3 to manage Erlang project dependencies. The project runs well, but the my IDE cannot resolve the functions of the dependencies. Here are my demo projects:

```
rebar3_module_a (a rebar3 lib module)
rebar3_module_b (a rebar3 lib module)
rebar3_app (the main rebar3 app)
```

rebar3_app use rebar3_module_a and rebar3_module_b ad it's dependencies.
(see screen capture below):

Is there anyone know how to make my IDE resolve the dependencies well?

[image]

thanks ~~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

issue resolved by adding the dependencies into project's modules.

refer to the screen capture bellow:

[image]